# Gimp prints new font invisibly

Tags: fonts, gimp

Gimp beginner here! I'm trying to design a logo with a new font I just bought, but I'm having trouble. I've figured out how to add text, I've changed the color to be different than the background, the text is on the top layer, and the new font is detected (I found posts related to all these issues while trying to solve this). However, when I actually type, the text doesn't show up. If I choose a different font, it is visible. Screen capture attached. Has anyone seen this before? The font I'm trying to use is Halycoon Script

[image: GIF of changing fonts to show/hide text]

Comment: Could simply be a poorly encoded font.. especially if it's a "free font". The fact that changing the font works fine, is a clear indicator the problem is with the font file itself - either its installation or its construction.

Comment: Thanks for the response! It was not free, but it was pretty inexpensive. Is there any way to check something like that? It does show up in Paint 3D, and the designer said they use it in Photoshop, but I don't have Photoshop.

Answer (score 1):

I had originally installed the TTF files. I un-installed the font and re-installed using OTF, and the font now shows up! Thanks @Scott for pointing me in the right direction with your comments!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted `:)`